# How to triangulate a polygon using Python?

Tags: python, scripting, geometry

I often meet the following problem: mapping a point on the surface of a polygon in 3D coordinates to the corresponding polygon in a UV map.

To do that, the only way I've found is to:

- Triangulate the mesh (by copying the original, and use `bmesh.ops.triangulate`
- Then use a barycentric transform with `barycentric_transform` from `mathutils.geometry`

I'd like to avoid copying and triangulating the whole mesh.

My question is: how to transform on the fly the list of vertex indices associated to a polygon (which seems to be a fan) into a list of tris the same way `bmesh.ops.triangulate` does it (or in a coherent other way)?