# Convex or concave hull, depending on quad or non quad, why this behavior?

Tags: faces, geometry

Related to this [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79260/how-to-triangulate-a-polygon-using-python), I've tried to understand how triangles are interpreted in Blender.

Doing these experiments, the result is a bit surprising and I'd want to know why.

Starting from a quad, I obtain this (see gif below): kind of convex hull is calculated and the faces are overlapping only for first and third vertex in fan point of view:

[image]

But if we test that for a polygon with more than 4 vertices, it does not happen anymore:

[image]

Surely, I've not tested it for all configurations (all vertex amount), but it seems to be a rule.

Why? And, by the way, how this behavior has a link to my original [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79260/how-to-triangulate-a-polygon-using-python)?

In hope the title of this new question is good enough, this time, thanks for any information.

Comment: Title skills over 9k.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I showed a [similar example](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/56781/935) to your first before. The quad is always cut from vert 0 to vert 3, while n-gons are triangulated using a better algorithm, possibly because the possibility of concave faces is more likely.

You will also find that an n-gon is triangulated dynamically as you alter it.

[image: editing an ngon]

I expect the tri/quad drawing code was left alone when n-gon support was added. Maybe it could be suggested that the work being done for 2.80 could include the use of same drawing algorithm for all faces.

Comment: I suspect that the tri/quad drawing code was left alone in case changing it interfered with proper display of files created with legacy versions.

Comment: FYI, finally found BM_face_calc_tessellation in bmesh_polygon.c does the job. Simple and hard coded for 3 and 4 (depending on a flag) vertices and much more complex for > 4... (@brasshat)