# Is there a way to fix these weird faces without adding more polygons?

Tags: modeling

Imported mesh from Maya over to Blender. The shading and faces are weird.
Here's the blend file, mega.nz/#!N3RTgRwD!b2t7DqLzu3H7MyUrZ5SDdfC8wZW3mngz2LzeHe6jY2E

[image: Blender]

Here it is in Maya.
[image: Maya.]

Comment: Maybe related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76513/strange-black-shading-cannot-fully-light-mesh-cycles. Not black here but seems the same, mesh with even that amount of faces should be relatively smooth once shading is set to Smooth.

Comment: Are you sure shading is set to smooth? You may also want to use the "Triangulate Faces" function to see if that helps.

Comment: I tried the Clear Custom Split Normals Data, turning off Auto smoothing, and the triangulate modifier. Shading is on smooth, here it is flat, https://gyazo.com/4c06dc701244220f399bdcda8fc24747

Comment: Maybe every face is separated?  Try remove double?  And.. try turning off viewport ambient occlusion?  And if you are in Cycles mode, Cycles do have problem shading low polys up close on screen.

Comment: It looks like you have view port ambient occlusion turned on.  From what I can tell the viewport ao doesn't recognize quads and likes to shade the quad's underlying triangle structure.

Comment: @LukasValine Woo! Thank you Lukas, that seemed to have been the problem.

Answer (score 2):

While we model using quads, blender always draws to screen using triangles. The current triangulating algorithm for quads always triangulates the same way, while the newer ngon triangulating is more intelligent, see [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/79270/935) for some more insight.

While the vertex order used to make each face could be re-arranged to get a better result, I don't think there is an easy way to do that.

You should find that a subsurf modifier will hide most of the effect you are seeing.